# Is it safe to remove files/folders from .cache?

Tags: cache

My .cache folder is occupying over 6GB of space. It is safe to delete it? The contents of my .cache are:

`bazel  dconf  fontconfig  jedi  matplotlib  motd.legal-displayed  pip`

Comment: Safe.  Most applications only store there data that should be trivial.  In some cases it's even desirable to remove data in such directories, [for example pip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9510474/3701431)

Comment: You could consider keeping the `~/.cache/dconf` though

Comment: sure, but it won't stop it from comming back. It might be better to check each of the application responsible and check for a setting.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy any particular reason for retaining the dconf folder? Sorry, I am not very familiar with all this.

Comment: @user110327  dconf is database of user settings. In `~/.cache` there should be only temporary data, not critical in any way.  More critical would be in `~/.config`, however I am making a guess  that ~/.cache/dconf` may contain very recent changes that haven't been added to `~/.config` yet.   Again, it shouldn't contain critical information and I don't have solid evidence, just a suggestion

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy can you please post an answer so that i can accept it? thanks!

Comment: @user110327 I've provided an answer, which should be more or less formal but the question has been asked in the past, so I voted this post to be closed. If you think it doesn't quite fit, let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [XDG specifications](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/ar01s03.html):

> $XDG_CACHE_HOME defines the base directory relative to which user specific non-essential data files should be stored. If $XDG_CACHE_HOME is either not set or empty, a default equal to $HOME/.cache should be used.

So in other words, it is safe to remove items from it. Most applications only store there data that should be trivial (and of course the emphasis is on *should*, because it is up to the application to handle what they put in the directory). For instance, Google Chrome and Chromium browsers cache web pages and media in that directory, but significant configuration files are stored in `/home/<username>/.config/google-chrome/default`. In some cases it's even desirable to remove data in `~/.cache` directory, for example [for pip to install desired version of package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9510474/3701431).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can delete all of .cache with no long term detrimental effects.

If your .cache is growing large, it might be better to look at the contents and try to determine what application is making it large and re-configure a bad acting application.

In some case for application's custom configuration may cause problem.For the reason it is bad habit to delete things you do not understand in your home directory, back it up or use a test account.

 so have backup and then try

```
mv .cache .cache_backup
```